# Django PermissionRequiredMixin - return 404 error instead of 403

Tags: django, django-views, authorization

I'm trying to return a 404 instead of a 403 when using the PermissionRequiredMixin in a class based view, I don't want a user to see a 403 as then it means the url exists

```
class SomeobjectCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Someobject
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some_url')
    fields = ['field1', 'field2', ...]
    template_name = 'someobjects/someobject_new.html'
    permission_required = 'someobjects.permission'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be custimizing the 403 template

project/urls.py

```
handler403 = 'your_app.views.handler403'
```

Now in the 403 view you can render the 404 template.

```
def handler403 (request, *args, **kwargs):
     return render(request, '404.html')
```